# Filter multidimension array with conditional logic

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have below array,

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [location] => X33 [usernumber] => 1 [order] => XX [part_number] => Hi ) [1] => Array ( [location] => X33 [usernumber] => 1 [order] => XX [part_number] => 68730 ) [2] => Array ( [location] => W33 [usernumber] => 2 [order] => YY [part_number] => 68741) [3] => Array ( [location] => W33 [usernumber] => 2 [order] => YY [part_number] => Hello )
```

I want to filter this array with usernumber = 1, by this it will create 1 array with arrays which have usernumber = 1, similarly it will create for usernumber=2

I had users in DB and will search user in this array,

I tried below code,

```
$users = $this->admin_model->get_usersforshipment();
foreach ($users as $user) {

  $filtered = array_filter($csv_array, function($user)

   { //Below is retrurning as orignal $csv_array, not filtered,
    return !empty($user['usernumber']); 

  });

}
```

Desired output, when $users['usernumber] == 1

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [location] => X33 [usernumber] => 1 [order] => XX [part_number] => Hi ) [1] => Array ( [location] => X33 [usernumber] => 1 [order] => XX [part_number] => 68730 ) )
```

Desired output, when $users['usernumber] == 2

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [location] => W33 [usernumber] => 2 [order] => YY [part_number] => 68741) [1] => Array ( [location] => W33 [usernumber] => 2 [order] => YY [part_number] => Hello )
```

How can i filter only 2 arrays from Multi Dimension array?

Comment: use `array_column` and then use `foreach` with array_search.

Comment: can you show what is your desire output? How is `$filtered` looks like after the filter?

Comment: @FrayneKonok, updated desired output

Comment: Your answer is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Online Example](https://3v4l.org/G3sl6), Description added after your feedback.

```
$arr = array(
        array ('location' => 'X33',
               'usernumber' => 1,
               'order' => 'XX', 
               'part_number' => 'Hi'
              ),
        array ('location' => 'X33',
               'usernumber' => 1,
               'order' => 'XX',
               'part_number' => '68730' 
               ),
        array ('location' => 'W33',
               'usernumber' => 2,
               'order' => 'YY',
               'part_number' => '68741'
               ),
        array ('location' => 'W33',
               'usernumber' => 2,
               'order' => 'YY',
               'part_number' => 'Hello'
              )
    );

$out = array();
$index = $arr[0]['usernumber'];
foreach($arr as $val){
    if($index != $val['usernumber'])
        $index = $val['usernumber'];
    $out[$index][] = $val;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, able to get desired output now! Danke!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your array is defined like so:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'location' => l1
        'usernumber' => 1
        'order' => 'o1'
    ],
    1 => [
        'location' => l2
        'usernumber' => 1
        'order' => 'o2'
    ],
    2 => [
        'location' => l3
        'usernumber' => 2
        'order' => 'o3'
    ]
];
```

A good solution would be to set the `usernumber` variables as array keys. You could do this while creating the array, or you could alter it after creation. It should look like this:

```
$array = [
    1 => [ // The key is now the usernumber
        [
            'location' => 'l1'
            'order' => 'o1'
        ],
        [
            'location' => 'l2'
            'order' => 'o2'
        ]
    ],
    2 => [
        [
            'location' => 'l3'
            'order' => 'o3'
        ],
    ]
];
```

Now you can simple grab the different orders by the usernumber and loop through them:

```
$orders = $array[1]; // Get all orders from the user with usernumber 1

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    print_r($order);
}
```

Comment: This helped me to get specific array with ce number!